# Adding key property to every object in array of objects on action dispatch

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Here is my problem,
I have a state in my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    arrOfObjects: [
       {name: 'John', age: 30, nickname: 'Johnny'},
       {name: 'Jack', age: 31, nickname: 'Jackie'},
       {name: 'Bill', age: 32, nickname: 'Billie'}
   ]
}
```

I dispatch an action

```
axios.all(personIds.map(el => axios.get(`/people/${el}/persons`)))
.then(res => {
  for (let per in res) {
    dispatch(personLastname(res[per].data.lastname))
     }
 });
```

Then I do this in my reducer

```
case actionTypes.PERSON_LASTNAME:
            return{
                ...state,
                arrOfObjects: state.arrOfObjects.map(person => ({
                    ...person,
                    _lastname: action.lastname
                }))
            }
```

So the problem is that with this approach, I add key property to every object inside array but every object has the same key value, the last value that is dispatched.

```
const initialState = {
    arrOfObjects: [
       {name: 'John', age: 30, nickname: 'Johnny', _lastname: 'Smith'},
       {name: 'Jack', age: 31, nickname: 'Jackie', _lastname: 'Smith'},
       {name: 'Bill', age: 32, nickname: 'Billie', _lastname: 'Smith'}
   ]
}
```

How can I add this key property _lastname to every object but in the order like I am getting when dispatching the action  , first lastname should go to John object, second to Jack and so on... I hope this make any sense.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

this is how a personLastName function looks like:

```
export const personLastname = lastname => {
    return{
        type: PERSON_LASTNAME,
        lastname: lastname
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `personLastName()` function look like?

Comment: @samanime I edited the question and added personLastname function.

Comment: Also how does `res` you get from api look?

Comment: If I console.log(res[per].data.lastname) in the for loop I always get lastnames in order that it should be.

Comment: yeah, but how does `console.log(res)` look like?

Comment: When logging res, i have 3 objects, and every object has data object with lastname property inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1: Call action after each axios call is resolved.

```
axios.all(personIds.map(el => axios.get(`/people/${el}/persons`).then(res => {
  dispatch(personLastname(res.data.lastname)) // Assuming you get response with data prop
})));
```

Approach 2: Send the action with the whole array as payload instead of individual item and handle matching in the reducer. This assumes that order of last name objects in your resp is the same as on the state.

```
axios.all(personIds.map(el => axios.get(`/people/${el}/persons`)))
  .then(res => dispatch(personLastname(res));

export const personLastname = people => {
    return{
        type: PERSON_LASTNAME,
        people: people
    }
}    


case actionTypes.PERSON_LASTNAME:
  return {
    ...state,
    arrOfObjects: state.arrOfObjects.map((person, i) => ({
      ...person,
      _lastname: action.people[i].data.lastname
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Clarity. Second approach  is the solution. Thank you very much.